# Condition for product of two matrices to be a null matrix.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Consider two matrices $A$ (a 4x4 matrix) and $B$ (a 4x1 matrix) with atmost 4 non zero entries.

$A$ is invertible, i.e., its determinant is not 0.

My question is, can we say that $AB$ will always be a non zero matrix? If yes, how do we prove it theoretically/mathematically?

If both $A$ and $B$ were square matrices, I could have used the condition that the determinant of either is not 0, so the product also cannot be 0. But how do I do it if B is not a square matrix?

In general, if the product of two matrices is 0, it is not necessary for either of the matrices to be 0, right? When does the product of two non zero matrices equal 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is assumed to be invertible, then one can multiply both sides of $AB=0$ by $A^{-1}$ to obtain the consequence $A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}0$, or $B=0$. In other words, when $A$ is invertible, then $AB=0$ implies $B=0$. Indeed, when $A$ is invertible, then the equation $AB=C$ for a variable vector $B$ and a constant vector $C$ always has a unique solution, namely $B=A^{-1}C$.

It is certainly possible in general for the product $AB$ of two matrices to be $0$ when neither of them is individually $0$. The smallest example is when $A=(1\ 0)$ (a $1\times2$ matrix) and $B=(0\ 1)^T$ (a $2\times1$ matrix). Any matrix $A$ that has a nontrivial null space will also lead to examples, where all the columns of $B$ are vectors in the null space.